# Swing: Positioning a popup from within a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, popup, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside of a `JScrollPane`. I am creating a custom cell editor for one of the columns of the table, and I want this editor to pop up a scrolling `JList`. I've done this by using a `Popup` to show a new `JScrollPane` containing the `JList`.

Everything is working, except for the position of the `Popup`. My custom component for the editor looks basically like this:

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    JList list = new JList();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    Component owner = null;
    public CustomPanel(Component owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
        add(text);
    }
    public void showPopup() {
        Popup p = PopupFactory.getPopup(owner, scroll, getX(), getY()+getHeight());
        p.show();
    }
}
```

What is happening is that `getX()` and `getY()` are returning the position of the table cell relative to the JScrollPane holding it, and `Popup` is wanting absolute screen position. Even if I pass in `owner` the `JScrollPane` that they are relative to, it doesn't work. I get the same problem if I use `text.getX()` / `text.getY()`.

How can I position my `Popup` directly below the `TextBox`?

Just a bit more background: The end goal is a multiple-select combobox that displays all of the selected items as a comma-separated list. If something else like this already exists, please don't hesitate to point me to it.

Edit: `owner.getLocationOnScreen().y + getY()` doesn't work when the scroll pane is anywhere but scrolled all the way up. However, just plain `getLocationOnScreen().y` DOES work. Problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the absolute screen position with [`Component.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()). Is that what you're looking for?